# OnClick event of my LinkButton is never triggered

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, linkbutton

I want to generate dynamic dropdownlists and a linkbutton based on a selectedItem from a dropdownlist. Here the scenario:
1. User selects a familyname from "ddlFamily"
2. Dynamic ddls and "submitAnswers" linkbutton will be created. These ddls will include some specific questions related to the selected family. Users will select answers from the dynamically created ddls.
3. User will click the linkbutton and save the answers.

My problem is, when I click the linkbutton, the buttonclick event "SubmitAnswers_Click" is never triggered. I could not find and fix why. My code is on the below:

```
protected void ddlFamily_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                questions = GetQuestions();
                int counter = 0;
                while (counter < questions.Count)
                {
                    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                    ddl.ID = "dynamicDDL" + counter.ToString();
                    ddl.Items.Add(questions[counter]);
                    String q2 = "SELECT ANSWERID, answer FROM Answer WHERE questionID="+questionIDs[counter];
                    ReturnResultViaQueryToDB(answers, answerIDs, q2);
                    for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ddl.Items.Add(answers[i]);
                    }
                    pnlFamily.Controls.Add(ddl);
                    counter++;
                    answers.Clear();
                    answerIDs.Clear();
                    howManyDDLCreated++;
                }
                if (howManyDDLCreated > 0)
                {
                    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
                    lb.ID = "bnSubmitAnswers";
                    lb.Attributes.Add("AutoPostBack", "true");
                    lb.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    lb.Click += new EventHandler(submitAnswers_Click);
                    lb.Text = "Submit Answers";
                    pnlProvince.Controls.Add(lb);
                }
            }
        }
        protected void submitAnswers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < howManyDDLCreated; i++)
            {
                var currentDynamicDDL = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("DynamicDDL" + i);
                String s = currentDynamicDDL.Text;
//save answers here
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance for all helps. I appreciate.

By the way, I checked the asked questions and found some similar ones. However, I could not find an appropriate answer, unfortunately. Very sorry if any and if I miss.

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

This is down to the page life cycle of web forms. If you add controls to the aspx markup then the code behind will handle creation of these controls on post back. If you create dynamic controls then you need to recreate them yourself at the appropriate stage of the life cycle. The Page_init event is the safest place and should allow the view state to populate the state and fire the event. You will need to reattach the event handler. Microsoft will tell you more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here, the dynamic controls should be created based on the selected family, since each family has different number of questions. How can I create the ddls in Page_init, in that case?

Comment: Think of it in terms of page load or page post back. You already do the creation in the page load. Your specific issue is a dynamically added button not firing its click event. Recreating the button in page_init is the answer to your question. Read the link I attached and try to learn the page life cycle. This should help you answer the other question re the ddls. Feel free to mark this as the right answer if it has helped.

Comment: Sorry, I still could not fix it. To be clear:

When page comes first - only a ddl (family) on the screen. User selects an item, then based on this item, dynamic ddls need to be created. Page_init event does not reach the selected item since it is fired before SelectedIndex_change. So how can I create the ddls in Page_init without knowing the selected family. When I try Page_Load, buttonClick event is again not fired..

Comment: Your question was about the button event not firing. Have you read the link, recreated the button in init and got the event firing. You need to learn the page life cycle before the problem can be solved. Your question was about the button click so solve that first then raise a separate question re ddls.